# similarity between 2 symbols oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, similarity, fuzzy, sentence-similarity

Table with rows more than 3 million names (Name, surname, father name). I want check similarity more than 90%. 
I used many fuzzy algorithms and also utl_match similarities (jaro_winkler , edit_distance). **Performance of these algorithms is not good**. (more than 20 sec.) 
and  i want check with changing places, but it works long. Like:
Name Surname Fathername,
Name Fathername Surname,
Surname Name Fathername,
.........
I couldnt find any algorithm with good performance, **it works on transactional system**.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing you might first want to take offline, outside of Oracle.  See what tools/algorithms work well, and then if you really have the need to do this against a production database, come back and worry later.

Comment: Thanks for advice, now this is not a problem, but I'm trying to improve

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? If it's 11gR2 or higher you should have a look at the Name Search extension to Oracle Text. This will perform well, but unfortunately requires scheduled sync'ing so it may not be suitable for a transactional application. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/search.htm#CCAPP9534).

Comment: Before overly complaining about it being slow, think about the task your asking Oracle to do. Without some sort of preprocessing ( see suggestion by @Thomas ) you are asking it to perform 3M rows against 3M rows; that 9Trillion (9,000,000,000,000) comparisons. At 3 times in time you are complaining about that is still 2.5M comparisons per second. That is blazingly fast - just huge volume. You need to reduce that volume!

Comment: @belayer one name check with 3 million, not 3 mil x 3 mil.

Comment: Well that makes a lot more sense but that wasn't specified. "more than 3 million names... I want check similarity". That reads like checking each against each of the others. Maybe better phase would be "more than 3 million names I want I want to check **a** name ...'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check against all 3 million names every time because you have duplicates in your database. What you can do as well is precluster your entries in these with most distance and then use different entry points.

So in the first step create your entry points:

```
Miller
Smith
Yang
...
```

And check versus this entry points with > for example 70% and then go deeper to the clusters where you have a quite good match. This should prune most of the searches and make your algorithmn much faster.

Comment: thanks for comment, but there are not dublicated names. 
i used sundex and jaro winkler it's much better